# Find all automorphisms of the ring $ \mathbb{Z} $.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

I know that a automorphism is a isomorphism of the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

So, f: $\mathbb{Z}$ $\to$ $\mathbb{Z}$ is an isomorphism then the following statements hold true:

i) f is bijective

ii) f is an homomorphism of rings such that:

1. f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)
2. f(xy) = f(y)f(x)   $\forall$ x, y $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$

1 and 2 are valid for all integers x, y. And f: $\mathbb{Z}$ $\to$ $\mathbb{Z}$ is bijective, so, all integers are isomorphism ?therefore all integers are automorphisms of the ring $ \mathbb{Z} $? Or I understood this wrong?

Comment: "All integers are isomorphism" What do you mean by this? An isomorphism must be a function. An integer is, by itself, not a function. You appear to have greatly confused what is being asked.

Comment: An isomorphism is a function. $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ your function. 
What the formula of your function?
If $f(x)=x$, then $f(x)$ is an automorphism.
If $f(x)=x+1$, then $f(x)$ is not an automorphism.

Comment: So, not all function $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is an automorphism.

Comment: There is no formula in the exercise, it’s just that f:$\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $f$ has to be unital, that is, if $f(1)=1$, then there is only one.

If not, then because of condition $2.$, we have that $f(1)^2=f(1)$.  That is, $f(1)$ is *idempotent*.  There are only two idempotent elements of $\Bbb Z$, namely $1$ and $0$.  So there are (at most) two.  But actually only one, because we know $f(0)=0$, so if $f(1)=0$, then $f$ isn't bijective.